# how to send data in another page with html and ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, cordova

i'm starting delevope android application with `phonegap`
as you may know i can't use `php` file in front-end of my app,
so i have a list that create dynamic
when user click on the each link go to the `singers_category.html` and base of the the `$genre_id` i want load group of singers on `singers_category.html`;
i'm try using `QueryString` but i'm think i can't using `QueryString` in html page;
so this is my code of php handler:
(i'm using switch case to using multiple handler in one page)

```
<?php
include('db_inc.php');
$functionId=$_GET['functionId'];
echo "$functionId <br>";
switch($functionId){
    case "":
    $singer_id =$_POST['last_items'];
    $result = $connection->query("SELECT * from genre")or die($connection->error);
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $genre_name = $row->genre_name;
            $genre_id = $row->genre_id;
            echo "<li><a href='singers_category.html?$genre_id >$genre_name</li>";
            }
            $connection->close;
            break;
    }


?>
```

my question is:how to access specific `$genre_id` with `ajax` and `html` and one `php` handler in `singers_category.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this issue we can use this script:
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

You would capture the item to be returned in JS like this:

```
function CloseWindow() {
        var hidchg = document.getElementById('<%=hidItemsChanged.ClientID %>');
        window.opener.TransDataChange(hidchg.value);
        window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();
        return false;
    }
```

and capture in sending page like this:

```
function TransDataChange(changeMade) {
if (changeMade == "true") {
    //..do something    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The format that you use is

```
 echo "<li><a href='singers_category.html?genre=" . $genre_id . "'>" . $genre_name . "</a></li>";
```

After this, in your code you can read that by:

```
$_GET['genre']
```

Comment: no problem with format my code is work,the problem is all of the page is `html` and we can use ajax and html only to send data to `php` handler

Comment: so whats the problem here? I could not really get it.